# PropTypes defined, but never used (ESLint, babel 6)

Tags: reactjs, webpack, eslint

I can't catch a place, where I'm fault.

my .eslintrc

```
{
  "extends": "eslint:recommended",
  "parser": "babel-eslint",
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "node": true
  },
  "plugins": [
    "react"
  ],
  "rules": {
    "no-console": 0,
    "new-cap": 0,
    "strict": 0,
    "no-underscore-dangle": 0,
    "no-use-before-define": 0,
    "eol-last": 0,
    "quotes": [2, "single"],
    "jsx-quotes": 1,
    "react/jsx-no-undef": 1,
    "react/jsx-uses-react": 1,
    "react/jsx-uses-vars": 1
  }
}
```

My webpack.config section about lint:

```
preLoaders: [
  {
    test: /\.js$/,
    loaders: ['eslint'],
    include: [
      path.resolve(__dirname, "src"),
    ],
  }
],
```

And my component

```
import React, { PropTypes, Component } from 'react'

export default class User extends Component {
  render() {
    const { name } = this.props
    return <div>
      <p>Hello, {name}!</p>
    </div>
  }
}

User.propTypes = {
  name: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired
}
```

I have exception:
  1:17  error  "PropTypes" is defined but never used  no-unused-vars

Hmm, what I'm doing wrong?

P.S. With babel5 - all works correctly.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
User.propTypes = {
  name: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired
}
```

You're already importing `React.PropTypes` as `PropTypes`, so in this case, just change this to `name: PropTypes.string.isRequired` (or remove the PropTypes import on top)

Comment: Thanks, this was driving me crazy